# How to install j2objc

Tags: swift, macos, installation, j2objc

Yesterday I ran "make dist" but compiling was more than 4 hours(I don't know, which time it could, if I didn't press stop). Today I run "make dist" again and compiling very long time again. Is it normal?
I have Mac mini 2012, 10gb ram.

Comment: You question is about installing j2objc? Or do you want to know why compiling takes long?

Comment: About installing j2objc:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal because by default make only runs one build task at a time. Try running "make -j8 dist", which tells make to run up to 8 tasks at a time.

The easiest way to install j2objc is to download and unzip [its most recent distribution](https://github.com/google/j2objc/releases).